# How to integrate with Facebook in iPhone?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to develop a Facebook integration in my iPhone apps and is there any way to customize the Facebook integration so please tell me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you google? There are many many questions asked here on SO for exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the facebook API at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api
You can use the webservices provided by facebook which ill let your application communicate to it with xml/JSON

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has written an SDK for iOS. You can get up and running with their documentation.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Try [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/docs/) or [FBConnect](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Check out theses links, All your answers are present.

1. [Tutorial for FBConnect](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)
2. [Add a Like Button](http://petersteinberger.com/2010/06/add-facebook-like-button-with-facebook-connect-iphone-sdk/)